# find value exist in a array of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of array, how to find if a value exists inside this array in javascript. Here is the code example

```
let multival = [['Individual'], ['Non-Individual'],null]
```

Now I have to find if string 'Non-Individual' is present in this array of array or not, can anyone have solution in this regards

Comment: Try `multival.flat().includes('Non-Individual')`

Comment: what result do you expect? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check the string is present in the array of array.

```js
const multival = [['Individual'], ['Non-Individual'], null];
const searchItem = 'Non-Individual';
const ret = multival.some(
  (x) => Array.isArray(x) && x.some((y) => y === searchItem)
);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, a recursive solution for arrays with any level of nested depth (And I believe quicker than a solution using `flat()` due to short circuiting):

```js
function nestedIncludes(arr, val) {
  let check = i => Array.isArray(i) ? i.some(check) : i === val;
  return arr.some(check);
}

let myArr = [[[['foo'],1],2],3,5];
let test = nestedIncludes(myArr, 'foo');
console.log(test); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function:

```js
const multival = [['Individual'], ['Non-Individual'],null]

const exists = multival.flat().includes('Non-Individual');

console.log(exists ? 'exists' : 'non-exists')
```

*Note: I didn't notice, but [User863](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8053274/user863) comment with the same answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Method 1, Using `findIndex`, optional chaining and `includes` 
Method 2, Using `some`, optional chaining and `includes`

```js
// Method 1, Using `findIndex` and `includes`
const find = (arr, item) => arr.findIndex((arr2) => arr2?.includes(item)) > -1;

// Method 2, Using `some` and `includes`
const find2 = (arr, item) => arr.some((arr2) => arr2?.includes(item));

let multival = [["Individual"], ["Non-Individual"], null];

console.log(find(multival, "Individual"));
console.log(find2(multival, "Individual"));

console.log(find(multival, ""));
console.log(find2(multival, ""));
```